# JavaScript error on click in DataGrid table after update to Wicket 9

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff

I have updated my application from Wicket 8.8.0 to 9.2.0 Unfortunately the links in a table do not work anymore after that. As table I use the DataGrid from wicketstuff-inmethod-grid.
The JavaScript error when clicking on a table row is:

> "An error occurred while executing Ajax request: TypeError:
> InMethod.XTable is undefined"

Another JavaScript error when refreshing the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: InMethod.XTableManager is undefined

What could be the reason?

Content Security Policy is disabled (getCspSettings().blocking().disabled()), because otherwise my css files were not found.
I use not by wicket managed

```
bootstrap.css (Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5) 
mdb.css (Material Design for Bootstrap 4)
```

Also not managed JavaScript:

```
bootstrap.js (Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5)
bootstrap-confirmation.js (Bootstrap: tooltip.js v3.3.7)
mdb.js (Material Design for Bootstrap 4)
```

I use Java 11 and among others the following dependencies:

```
"org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-inmethod-grid:9.2.0"
"org.apache.wicket:wicket-auth-roles:9.2.0"
"org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:9.2.0"
"org.apache.wicket:wicket-native-websocket-javax:9.2.0"
"org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:9.2.0"
```

The relevant part of <head> of generated HTML:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.resource.JQueryResourceReference/jquery/jquery-3.5.1-ver-1606382888000.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery-ver-1606382888000.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/js.RemoteControlDummyHookClass/remotecontrol-ver-1602070208000.js"></script>
</head>
```

Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: No other JavaScript errors on the console?

Comment: @svenmeier There is another error ("InMethod.XTableManager is undefined").

Comment: Check the browser Dev Tools' Network tab. It seems InMethod's JavaScript files are not loaded at all for some reason.

Comment: @martin-g Network tab shows that JavaScript (script-jq.js) is loaded (HTTP 200).

Comment: Please paste the `<head>...</head>` part of the generated HTML

Comment: @martin-g i've added the relevant HTML head and network tab from dev tools

Comment: There is no script-jq.js in your HTML `head`. If this is the real HTML then this explains the problem.